# How to keep fluid grid of image thumbnails from shifting during load?

Tags: html, image, gridview, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I'm using a bootstrap 3 fluid grid to display thumbnails, and I love how the images scale in size as the browser is resized. The downside however, is a "big bang" effect when each page is loaded. That is, the grid begins collapsed then grows as images are added. I imagine a simple fix is to hardcode image sizes, but this would lose the scaling benefit I believe.

One attempt to fix this was to load a transparent placeholder image right before each thumbnail, which would of course be cashed on the first page of results and thus expand the grid faster. On callback for thumbnail loaded event, I remove the placeholder. This seems to help, but other times I still see the shifting as badly as before. In addition, with a slow connection you can actually for a moment see the real thumb below the placeholder.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        // For each thumbnail, insert a placeholder image.
        // Once the thumb is loaded, remove the placeholder.
        $("[id^=thumb-]").each(function(i, thumb) {
            var $thumb = $(thumb)
            var imgTag = "<img id='ph-" + (i + 1) +
                "' class='placeholder' src='{% static "img/placeholder.png" %}'/>";
            $thumb.parent().prepend(imgTag);
            var $holder = $thumb.prev();
            function loaded() {
                $holder.remove();
            }
            if (thumb.complete) {
                loaded();
            } else {
                $thumb.on('load', loaded);
                $thumb.on('error', function() {
                    console.log('Error with thumbnail placeholders.');
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Regarding compatibility, I'd like to at least have a usable site with older browsers, but it doesn't have to be perfect.

I'm not as interested in fixing my Javascript solution above as I am the best solution overall.

**Please look at the live beta site [here](http://www.morphmarket.com/snakes/?page=11) to help diagnose.** I attempted a jsfiddle, but couldn't quite reproduce it. I will paste more context into the question once we understand what was wrong.

Comment: please post your html as well

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would recommend adding the `<img>` tag to the plain HTML. Then set the `src` in your javascript function.

You'll also need to set height and width attributes on the `<img>` tags so their space is preserved, to prevent redrawing the page after the images are loaded. You could do this with a simple javascript function that determines the `window.width` and then sets the height and width attributes.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/s7cp44yn/).

Comment: Thanks Brett, can you explain a bit more pls?  What benefit does setting src from JS provide?  Also, there's no way to defer computing height/width to fluid grid as I am doing now?

Comment: By adding the `<img>` tag in the HTML you van set the heoght amd width on page load, so the space is reserved to prevent the redrawing you're trying to eliminate. You can compute the window width on page load and set the width dynamically instead of a fixed eidth like I did.